# Python 2.7.11: How to read (big) binary file from/at hex offset

Tags: python, binary, hex, hexdump

So I have a large binary file (can range from 256mb and 2gb+, so memory can be an issue), and I only want some choice "lines" (read: from offset [(example of what I'm saying)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUjF4.png)) from the file.

[Example file. Image it being much much larger.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13VcM.png)

Lets say I wanted ONLY the data on the offset of 000000C0. How would I go about that?

Another thing that would help, is to read data from a certain offset to the end of the file/to another offset.

If this is possible, could I also only have it go from a little bit more precise input? E.G. 0000007C = 93 F8 43...rest of file.

And if we're keeping the from one offset to another, 0000007C to 0000007C = 93.

Also, writing to a file at those offsets could be a huge help as well.

How would I accomplish this while also keeping the offset human-readable (aka, keeping it similar to 00001200 or 00000070, ala the examples) for future use/dissection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a hexadecimal string to an integer using the `int(string, base=10)` function. From there, use the file handle's `.seek(offset)` to set your position. For example:

```
def read_from_hex_offset(file, hex_offset):
    """Fetch a single byte (or character) from file at hexadecimal offset hex_offset"""
    offset = int(hex_offset, base=16)
    file.seek(offset)
    return file.read(1)
```

Note that binary and text files can both be `seek`ed, and the results will differ - a binary file with `read()` bytes, while a text file will `read()` a string and try to deal with encoding. For your application, you should `open()` your file with a binary mode: `"rb"` or `"r+b"`.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use some other functions I had found online to get the hex values (AA, F2, etc), and edited the parameters to allow me to change the length that file.read gets.